# Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format) : Flickr upload api

Tags: rest, postman, flickr, flickrj

I tried lots of thing but fail to upload the photo through flickr api ..Here what i am doing

**API**-    https://api.flickr.com/services/upload

**Method**-  POST

**Authorization**- Oauth1.0

Passing `Consumer Key/Consumer Secret/Access Token/Token Secret`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 1):

Below video shows exactly how to create oath0.1 token

https://youtu.be/3gXPjj5iEAA

Follow the full video and once your setup is able to retrieve user details as in the video, create a copy of that and change the authorization 0auth0.1 to header than in request

and in body use form data , as name (just a name string)  and photo (actual file)
and do a POST.

**Steps summary:**

1. https://api.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token , request for token to this url
2. authorize the token you get by navigating to [https://api.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={{token}}](https://api.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=%7B%7Btoken%7D%7D)
3. Click the i will authorize button:

[image]

4. Copy the verifier code from the url navigated to
5. Get the access token through [https://api.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token?oauth_verifier={{verifier}}](https://api.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token?oauth_verifier=%7B%7Bverifier%7D%7D)
6. Access upload endpointing using this new token

**Output:**

[image]

**Postman Collection**

```html
<div class="postman-run-button"
data-postman-action="collection/import"
data-postman-var-1="ef7e250508f522b9bad1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function (p,o,s,t,m,a,n) {
    !p[s] && (p[s] = function () { (p[t] || (p[t] = [])).push(arguments); });
    !o.getElementById(s+t) && o.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild((
      (n = o.createElement("script")),
      (n.id = s+t), (n.async = 1), (n.src = m), n
    ));
  }(window, document, "_pm", "PostmanRunObject", "https://run.pstmn.io/button.js"));
</script>
```

**How to use the collection:**

use the gif file that i recorded to know the steps

https://www.flickr.com/photos/191341909@N02/50696475437/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: Thanks for your reply that i am already doing i didnt share screen shot it due to security reason thats why params are generating.

Comment: https://youtu.be/3gXPjj5iEAA full video of the exact stuff

Comment: this video didn't mention how upload API working.

Comment: It mentions how to do it

Comment: I tried same thing look like something i am still doing wrong

Comment: You can use the collection I created ,  just replace variables in pre request script don't change anything else

Comment: Click executr and it will show the run in postman button , you can use that to. Import collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225697/discussion-between-pdhide-and-subodh-joshi).